# Django RF, field level validation to check if requesting user is Admin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Django Rest Framework project have models field where any authenticated users can create model instance.

However I wanted to make sure that only Django Admin can change the `accepted` field value.

What is the best way to prevent other users from changing the `accepted` field ?

Pls note that I want to keep permission for authenticated users to create model instance keeping default `accepted`  field.

MODELS.PY

```
class PO(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    accepted=models.BooleanField(default=False) # I want this field to be changed only by admin user
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class POcreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = PO.objects.all()
    serializer_class = POserializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

SERIALIZER.PY

```
class POserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=PO
        fields='__all__'
```

Comment: any suggestions or directions will be appreciatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changed view layer and serializer

```
 def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return POAdminserializer
        return POserializer
```

```
class POAdminserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=PO
        fields='__all__'


class POserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=PO
        exclude=('created','accepted','delivered','rejected','rejected_reason')
```